# Pandas TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 text columns (the data is imported from excel and I'm using anaconda pandas v. 1.2.5, FWIW):

```
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column                     Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------                     --------------   ----- 
 0   Client Name: Trading Name  169532 non-null  object
 1   Policy Number              166950 non-null  object
```

I want to check if the rows are unique (ie no duplicate combinations).  So I run:

```
ops_uniq_cols = ['Client Name: Trading Name', 'Policy Number']
ops_u.groupby(ops_uniq_cols).size()
```

I get the error:
`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'int'`

How is this happening?  Neither of columns are time or int.

Update, here is some sample data:

```
Client Name: Trading Name   Policy Number
24419   Y Corporation   9742EA|BC0697|1
37963   PERFORMANCE LIMITED Y13333120A
14411   B KEN   56A439MVA
133801  Mutua   69285
109983  DANIEL & CO Y1212E0720A
```

None of it looks like date time to me.

Comment: What happens if you added an aggregator column like this: `ops_u.groupby(ops_uniq_cols)['Client Name: Trading Name'].size()`?

Comment: When I run: ```ops_u.groupby(ops_uniq_cols)['Client Name: Trading Name'].size()```, I still get the same error :(

Comment: among the `ops_uniq_cols` which one is time like column?

Comment: Hi @AnuragDabas, neither of them from what I can tell, here is a sample (with some names changed)

Comment: try `df.applymap(lambda x:type(x).__name__).eq("time").any()` and see what it returns

Comment: Hi @AnuragDabas, it does look like the Client Name is being treated as time...I'm not sure what to do about that though, the data looks like names to me.  Thank you for your help!
`Client Name: Trading Name     True
Policy Number            False`

Comment: Then just change the dtype of client Name to either datetime or int/float/string then try

Answer (score 0):

`df.applymap(lambda x:type(x).__name__).eq("time").any()` per @AnuragDabas did return a time, and I changed the dtype.